# 4-Momentum in Special Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I have been given the following question;

A ball of putty of mass $m$ travels at speed $v = 0.8$ towards another ball of putty of
mass $2m$, which is at rest. After the collision the balls are stuck together and the
combined lump has mass $M^\prime$ and speed $v^\prime$.

By comparing the components of the total 4-momenta before and after the collision
find the speed, $v^\prime$, of the combined lump after the collision.

I have tried doing the following
$$\textbf{p}_1=\left( m\gamma,\, m\gamma v,\, 0, \, 0  \right)$$
Here we see that the $y,z$ components of the 4-momentum evaluate to zero since the ball of mass $m$ only has velocity in the $x$ direction. When the balls of mass $m$ and $2m$ collide, we know that momentum is conserved. Namely;
$$\textbf{p}_b=\textbf{p}_a$$
Where there relative subscripts denote the 4-momentum before and after the collision. Since the particle with mass $2m$ is at rest, it clearly has no momentum, suggesting that;
$$\textbf{p}_b=\textbf{p}_1=\left( m\gamma,\, m\gamma v,\, 0, \, 0  \right)=\left( \frac{5}{3}m,\, \frac{4}{3}m,0,0 \right)$$
The momentum after the collision, is then;
$$\textbf{p}_a=\left(  M^\prime\gamma, \ M^\prime\gamma v^\prime, \, 0, \, 0  \right)$$
Thus, by comparing $\textbf{p}_a,\textbf{p}_b$, we see that;
\begin{align*}
    M^\prime \gamma &= \frac{5}{3}m \\
    M^\prime \gamma v^\prime &= \frac{4}{3}m
\end{align*}
From the first equation, we can see that;
$$\frac{5}{3}mv^\prime=\frac{4}{3}m\implies v^\prime=0.8$$

But I was expecting the velocity to be different after impact. Have I missed something?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.